# Conditional Ansible roles fail when already executed

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I have a role that I would like to execute multiple times, each execution with a different var. However, I would also like some of those executions to be conditional.

Here is a main.yml:

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - { role: test, test_files_group: 'a'}
    - { role: test, test_files_group: 'b', when: False}
```

Here is the main.yml from the 'test' role (`roles/test/tasks/main.yml`):

```
- name: List files
  command: "find . ! -path . -type f"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ role_path }}/files/{{ test_files_group }}"
  register: files
- debug: var=files.stdout_lines

- name: do something with the files
  shell: "echo {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ files.stdout_lines }}"
```

And here is part of the ansible-playbook command output:

```
TASK [test : List files] 

*******************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [test : debug] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "files.stdout_lines": [
        "./testfile-a"
    ]
}

TASK [test : do something with the files] **************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=./testfile-a)

TASK [test : List files] *******************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [test : debug] ************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [test : do something with the files] **************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'"}
```

Everything works for 'a' as expected, but then the `do something with the files` task is executed for b, even though I set `when: False`.

I feel like I'm missing something - what I'm wanting is for everything in `roles/test/tasks/main.yml` to be executed with the `test_files_group` var set accordingly, or not at all. What am I doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to read how `when` works with *includes* and *roles*.

In your case, `when: false` is attached to every task in the second run, so you have:

```
- name: List files
  command: "find . ! -path . -type f"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ role_path }}/files/{{ test_files_group }}"
  register: files
  when: false

- debug: var=files.stdout_lines
  when: false

- name: do something with the files
  shell: "echo {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ files.stdout_lines }}"
  when: false
```

1st and 2nd tasks are skipped (see your output), and in the the 3rd task `when` statement is applied to every iteration, but... at first Ansible tries to evaluate `with_items: "{{ files.stdout_lines }}"` and fails to do so, because *List files* task is skipped, so there are no `files.stdout_lines`.

If you want to fix this, use default for loop argument, e.g.:

```
with_items: "{{ files.stdout_lines | default([]) }}"
```

But I'd recommend to refactor your code and don't use "conditionals" with roles.